# AJAX MaskedEditExtender for phone numbers

Tags: .net, ajax, maskededitextender

I've read through the [Masked Edit and Phone Number](http://forums.asp.net/t/1216351.aspx) control at asp.net and browsed for a while on this subject but haven't found an answer as to why this behavior is occurring.
I have the following MaskedEditExtender defined for use with phone numbers.  I would like the mask to display prior to entering information into the textbox and remain both while making the entry and also after a valid entry.

```
<ajax:MaskedEditExtender ID="mee1" runat="server" Mask="999-999-9999" 
 AcceptNegative="None" MessageValidatorTip="true" TargetControlID="tbBox"
 MaskType="Number" ClearMaskOnLostFocus="false" ClearTextOnInvalid="false">
```

I believed a simple definition like the above would work, but the behavior of the form is erratic.  The mask is visible prior to entering a value (when the textbox is empty) but while entering the mask disappears.  Also, after the entry is made, the mask is no longer visible unless I click out of the textbox and then back into it.  Once I get the mask to reappear with the entry, it seems to remain.

Is this control broken or am I missing something basic?

Thanks much for any help!

Comment: I have found out (through selectively commenting out code) that it is related to a PreRender method on the TargetControlID textbox.  The method adjusts the width of the textbox based upon input through applying a style via TextBox.Attributes.Add().  This still doesn't explain why this is causing problems with the mask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this helps someone else.  This issue was caused by a single statement in a PreRender method.

```
tbBox.MaxLength = <some integer>;
```

Apparently by changing this simple value as a property of the textbox caused all sorts of strangeness.
If anyone has an idea of why this is causing the failure I'd love to hear it.
Thanks!